# I am having a jar file which I am calling from powershell script. As the jar runs google chrome crashes

Tags: google-chrome, powershell, jar

I am having a jar file which I am calling from powershell script. Now when I run the script the jar file is called and when jar tries to open google chrome, it crashes. If I try running the jar outside the powershell script it works perfectly fine. I think this is a machine specific issue, because the script ps script runs perfectly fine on other machines. any suggestions??

Comment: Have you checked that the version of Chrome, OS and any patches are consistent across all machines? Fairly noddy suggestion I know, but worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome's alternate installer. This will install Chrome for all users.

Link: [Alternate Installer](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html?system=true&standalone=1)

This often fixes problems if you are running Selenium as a background service.
**Passing '--no-sandbox'** flag when creating your *WebDriver* session.

Special test environments sometimes cause Chrome to crash when the sandbox is enabled.